# What do I open a .PY program with?

Tags: python

I've downloaded python for windows 7, however when I try to open a program it gives me a window to try to choose what program to open python with. I don't want to edit with notepad, I want to be able to use the default python idle editor.

Comment: With what OS? Windows : see https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-make-idle-the-default-editor-for-python-files-on-windows.cfm

Comment: You should click the option that lets you browse your system for an application to open it with. Find the python directory and select `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: Have you done any research? This seems rather straightforward, no? The title of your post doesn't reflect the actual question, by the way.

Comment: see the [ask] page on how to ask good questions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to absolutely open it that way then try to choose open with idle python, if you scroll down a bit in that selection window, else can you open idle python and click file - open - and the select the python file in the correct directory you want to open.